# How to create a dynamic array of dynamic stacks in C or C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, jagged-arrays

This is my C class programming homework:

> There is a train coming in to your terminal. Train has *N* cargoes and the cargoes are tagged from 1 to *N*. You have to send the cargoes out of your terminal in order from *N* to 1(like  `6 5 4 3 2 1`). `1 5 3 4 2` is an example of an incoming train which has 5 cargoes.
>
> Your terminal has a number of rails.This is how a terminal with 5 rails looks like:
>   [image]
>
> Only 3 operation are allowed in your terminal:
>
> 1. Send the cargo you received out of the terminal.
> 2. Send the cargo you received to a terminal rail.
> 3. Send the cargo from a rail out of the terminal.
>
> Example : The incoming train is  `1 2 3`.
>
> [image]
>
> INPUT : You have to receive an input as cargoes of a train, for example `1 2 3`. The input train has no more than 100 cargoes.
>
> OUTPUT : Show the fewest amount of rails possible to do the process, in the picture above, the output should be `1`.

I think my (psudo)code should look something like:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= cargoAmount;)
{
      if(i == trainin.top()) //found in IN: send the cargo out
      {
         trainin.pop(); 
         i++;
         continue; 
      }
      for(j = 0; j <= TotalStackCurrentlyInUse??; j++) //found in a RAIL: send the cargo out
      {
         if(i == rail[j].top())
         {
            rail[j].pop();
            i++;
            break; 
         }
      }
      if(j == TotalStackCurrentlyInUse) //Not found: Send the train to the rail stack
           SendTheTrainToTheRail(); 
           // I will try to write this thing later
           // I have the idea that the new cargo should have the value lass than rail[j].top()
 }
```

Now I think that I should use many dynamic stacks in my C application(each stack represents each rail in the terminal) and I should keep track of the number of the stack that the program uses. My friend tells me I should forget the whole stack thing and just use a linked list to create 100 `rail[j].head` first and then it'll go easy. But I just want to know how to do it using stacks(If it's hard and messy in C, I'm okay with C++ stacks and vectors).

Question : How to create a dynamic array of dynamic stacks in C or C++ and how to keep track of the number of stacks currently in use.(Note that I'm very new to C++ so this question might seems stupid)

Comment: Why one stack won't serve your purpose here...Is there a maximum number of cargos a rail can store???

Comment: it seems you only need one rail so long as it can hold 99 cars, or do some train arrive with the cars in a confused order?

Comment: with a train length limit of 100, it should be possible to just use static or auto allocation, worst case is 99 rails (99,98...2,1,100) , longest rail needed is 99. (1,2,...,99,100)

Comment: @Jasen Won't that consume the memory too much? It will cost 99*99 ints(or maybe 99*99 shorts).

Comment: If this is your C programming class, presenting a C++ solution may or may not result in points being awarded (and I'd be rather worried if it does). If this is your "C/C++" class, it's probably going to teach you neither.

Comment: @n.m. I just want to know how to code in C++ too. In my country, many competitions just state the compiler I should use and not the language. And what do you mean by "it's probably going to teach you neither"?

Comment: There is no such thing as "C/C++". There is C and there is C++. I have never seen anything remotely good labelled "C/C++". If you want to know how to code in C++ you need to learn to code specifically in C++ and not treat C++ as some nice optional extra on top of C.

Comment: @Santi-Santichaivekin 99 * 99 shorts is less than 40 Kilobytes  that was as a lot in 1980 but today,it's not so much unless this needs to run on on something with not much memory, then an array of lists probably a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply create a `std::vector<std::stack>` and loop over it. Your code modified:

```
  vector<stack> railStacks;//This should be accessible and appended to by `SendTheTrainToTheRail()`
  for(j = 0; j < railStacks.size() ; j++) //found in a RAIL: send the cargo out
  {
     if(i == railStacks[j].top())
     {
        railStacks[j].pop();
        i++;
        break; 
     }
  }
  if(j == railStacks.size()) //Not found: Send the train to the rail stack
       SendTheTrainToTheRail();
```

Comment: What happens when `railStacks[j].top()` is called while the stack is empty? Will it return 0 or will it just run wild?

Comment: You are right, it is UB in this case. After the call to `pop` you should erase the stack from `railStacks` if it is empty. Also, the `j==railStacks.size()` is not a safe check any more. You probably just want to maintain a `bool` with that info.

Comment: So I should create another vector in which each element represents the validity each stack?

Comment: Use the `empty` member function.